# Regular expression \p{f} and \p{Zs} in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm the new to regular expressions in JavaScript. I see the expressions in C# have the label,such as`"\p{f},\p{Zs},p{Lu},p{Lt},p{Lo}"`. But I add this in JavaScript , it doesn't work. So, how can I change these to JavaScript format that make it can work.